# How to slice a list based on row values?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7, cursor, list

I'm working with python 2.7 (quite a beginner).
I have a list, and I have a feature class with :

A = a field that contains values that I would like to use as the start of the slicing

B= a field that contains values indicating the number of items I need to take into my slicing.

Actually, I would like to do something like this :

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

rows = ap.SearchCursor(fc, fields = "A; B")

for row in rows:

    a = row.getValue("A")

    b = row.getValue ("B")

    newlist= list[a: (a+b)]
```

But its not working, I got an error "slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method"

Comment: I am pretty new to python too so i can't help with the code but the error message sounds like the field has the wrong format (text?) check that and try int(A)

Comment: Before using ArcPy, you need to learn Python:  [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/835653)

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your intended output?

Comment: @gene : thanks for the tip, but not really helping. I'm documented on slice notation, but I didn't find anything there that shows how to use values as slice parameters ... but maybe I din't  read enough carefully the 20 answers of that post.

Comment: a,b and a+b needs to be integers in the range of len(numList) = 12. You can try with int(a) and int(b)

Comment: @Aaron : my list contains actually julian days (from Mars to end of June) , my "A" field contains a julian day that corresponds to a visit day (of a nest) and my field "B" contains the number of days since the last visit. I want to use the "newlist" to calculate the average of weather conditions during that lapse of time.

Comment: If you had printed out the values of `a` and `b` prior to using them in `newlist= list[a: (a+b)]` then I think you would have been able to write a test code snippet that did not use ArcPy.  This may not seem obvious at the moment but I think it is where the comment by @gene is coming from.  Once you have a good sense of where the line between ArcPy and pure Python is, it makes debugging Python scripts that import ArcPy much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the working code for what you showed in the question.  However, keep in mind that everything is zero indexed, so if you want to start at the true numbered item in the list you need to reference a-1 instead of a.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\YourGDB.gdb\YourFC'

numList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("A", "B")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        a = int(row[0])
        b = int(row[1])
        newList = numList[a:(a+b)]
        print newList
        print " "
```

If you need to account for zero indexing:

```
newList = numList[(a-1):((a-1)+b)]
```